# OAuth: OAuth implementation use case

Tags: oauth

I have a webapp which does a lot of ajax requests with the php server and database server. I have also created an iPhone app and an Android app, which have been working as offline apps till now.

Now I want to create an API which will be used to sync data between web server and smartphone apps. Should I be using OAuth for this? What I have read about OAuth - it seems like it is used if I want to open my API to be used by third party apps. But here I just want to ensure secure transfer of data between API and my own apps.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main usage of `OAuth` is to make third-party apps authorized to access private resources of a user on a website without giving user credentials to the third-party app. For example, suppose that *Twitter* wants to get the list of contacts from your *Yahoo* account. The traditional way is to give your username and password to *Twitter*. But with `OAuth`, you give them a temporary token (called `Access Token`) which authorizes *Twitter* to access your contacts on *Yahoo* for a limited amount of time (until either this token expires or you, as the owner of private resource, explicitly revoke it).

That said, `OAuth` is not about securely transmitting data on the web. That's another story which is usually achieved using `SSL`. Even when you use `OAuth`, you have to use `SSL` alongside to make sure data is sent and received securely.

So in your case, you have to see what the API is used for. If it's public API which doesn't give any private data to the callers, there is no need to use `OAuth`. If the API is for accessing private resources of individual users however, You may consider using `OAuth`. If you opt to implement `OAuth`, you may allow other third-party apps to access your API in future without any concern.

Answer (score 0):

Well a lot depends on how you are securing your API. Is your API open to public specially the post urls? If your data is not something which every user should see, then how are you checking the authentication of the user credentials?

Most the important thing is that we should avoid sharing the username and password over the wire to check for authentication all the time. This means, your API should not require username and password to validate if the user is valid. Which you can do by sending the username and password from mobile or device id or some other thing.

In such situation, the OAuth server comes to the rescue. Basically, on one URL a user will send his username and password to get his access token. Once that is acquired, we can use the access token to validate each request and take necessary actions.

You can refer the videos where I have implemented OAuth server in Laravel 5 using bshaffer which is one of the best OAuth library for any PHP framework to user. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vGXbWdtjls